# Test Spring Boot Actuator Customized Endpoint

Tags: junit, endpoint, spring-boot-actuator, mockmvc

I'm trying to test a customized actuator endpoint  in springboot.

The endpoint is:

```
@Component
@RestControllerEndpoint(id = "test")
public class TestController {

  @PostMapping("/1")
  public ResponseEntity<?> testEndpoint(Request request) {
    }
}
```

Then I use MockMvc,

```
 @SpringBootTest
 @ActiveProfiles("test")
 public class MyControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private MyController myController;

  @BeforeEach
  public void setup() {
    this.mock =
            MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myController)
                    .build();
   }

  @Test
  public void test_1() throws Exception {
    Request request = new Request();
    request.setStatus("ok");

    mock.perform(
            post("/1")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(request))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
  }

}
```

Both  **post("/test/1")** and  **post("/1")** get 404 error. **This MockMvc test works for normal controllers**.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>
Expected :200
Actual   :404
```

And .yml file is

```
management:
  server.port: 8081
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /api/v1/mycontext
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide your whole test class please?

Comment: I feel that you should call ```/test/1``` and not ```/1```maybe?

Comment: neither of them works, actually, I already tried both

Answer (score 0):

Custom endpoints are added as a sub link under `actuator` endpoint. So the url of your custom end point should be `/actuator/test/1`. In this case it should be `/api/v1/mycontext/test/1` as you have set `management.endpoints.web.base-path`.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to enable the actuator endpoints in your test application config